# Stevenson's screen for backyard home brewing?

Tags: beer, brewing

I've moved into a house with no access under the house. I was thinking of brewing beer in a shadowy corner of the backyard.

My question is - is it practical to brew beer in your backyard using a box like a [Stevenson's screen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stevenson_screen)? (Or is there a specific alternative to this for home brewing?)

Assumptions:

- The weather outside is the Australian summer (15-35 degrees C). Direct exposure to the sunlight would probably wreck the brew.
- The point is to shelter the brewing process without having the odours in the house.
- This is about about fermenting outside in a shelter

Comment: I guess I don't understand the question.  If you're just going to brew in the backyard, it's fine.  But if you're also planning on fermenting outdoors, it's a totally different situation.

Comment: what Denny said ^ are you asking about fermenting outside in a shelter, or boiling up your wort and hops?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stevenson's screens are overkill for home brewers.  If I understand the utility of them, they are used to keep your utensils and tools clean and clear of the elements of brewing outside.  Most of these elements will not effect the outcome of your beer to such a dramatic level that you should be concerned enough to warrant using this sort of containment.

Brewing outside is part of the enjoyment of home brewing.  The open air, getting out of the house, enjoying the sun (unless you live in North America this time of the year); all of it plays into the hobby of homebrewing.  Use your patio table, place your equipment on a kitchen towel to keep the glassware from shattering.  Unless there is a rain storm which would dilute your beer, a hale storm that could damage your glassware, or a thunderstorm that would cause your better half to question your logic behind wielding a stainless steel spoon next to a stainless steel boil kettle, don't worry about it, relax, and enjoy the hobby... Unless it's snowing... In which case, go inside, it's warmer there.

Comment: I brew outside and love it, I have an old turkey frier and another propane burner that I use. I get the boil water started on the gas BBQ then move it to one of the other burners when they free up. and clean up isa breeze with the garden hose to rinse everything on the lawn
As for fermenting. even though I live in Socal, the temps vary more than I want, so I ferment in my living room. It usually stays about 65-72F in there and when the bubbles are going its a great conversation piece. I have never noticed any foul odors coming from it.